# Trying to populate a jQuery FullCalendar from Grails

Tags: javascript, jquery, grails, fullcalendar

I'm trying to display a jQuery FullCalendar (http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar) inside a Grails GSP and to populate it from a controller. Here is the Javascript code to initialize my calendar:

```
$('#container').fullCalendar({
  header: {
      left: 'prev,next today',
      center: 'title',
      right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
  },
  editable: false,
  firstDay: 1,
  events: '${createLink(controller: "myEvent", action: "events")}'
```

});

And my controller returns the following JSON (curtesy of Firebug):

```
[{"id":"1","title":"Devoxx 2010","allDay":true,"start":new Date(1289775600000),"end":new Date(1290121200000),"url":"http://www.devoxx.com"}]
```

And the problem is that I don't see anything appear in the calendar although I'm on the right month. No event is displayed and I don't get any errors. Any idea what may be missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If firebug is returning that exact string as you have it, it's not going to work because of the new Date() functions.  The dates should already be a date.  Not a function to create a date.  For example, my json looks like the following:

```
[{"id":"Board_Meeting_0","title":"Board Meeting","start":"Fri, 20 Aug 2010 14:00:00 CDT","end":"Fri, 20 Aug 2010 15:00:00 CDT","allDay":false}]
```

Comment: Yay, it works great now! Thanks a lot! In fact, fulllcalendar's documentation is a little misleading because it says start and end should be Date instances, not Strings, but then when you read the description it says it's a String. Anyways, to avoid having a String and have a Date Object instead, I had added the following parameter to my Grails config: grails.converters.json.date = 'javascript' All I had to do was to remove it or set it to grails.converters.json.date = 'default'. And now it works... almost. My events appear but the days are shifted. But I'll figure out that one. Thanks again!

Answer (score -2):

${...} does not look correct in jquery to return a function, just the function or $(...)